# Find an element in a list in Scala

Tags: scala, list, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a function *myfoo* which, taken an Int and a list of ints, verifies if the int element is in the list or not. It should return "true" if the int is in the list, false otherwise. 
I've written this function, but when I compile it it returns this error:

```
error: type mismatch;    
 found   : Unit   
 required: Boolean    
        breakable { for  (i <-l) {   
                          ^
one error found*
```

This is my program:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._

object findEl extends App{
    def myfoo (x:Int,l:List[Int]):Boolean={
        breakable { for  (i <-l) {
        i match {
            case a if (a==x) => true
            case _ => false
            break
            } 
        }
    }
}

    println(myfoo(1,List(1,2,3,4))) //should print "true"
}
```

How can I solve it? :)

Comment: I have to use necessary the "match" construct for exercise!

Comment: Did you specify "breakable" anywhere ??

Comment: Do you also have to use `breakable`? If not, you should match `l`, and not have any `for`.

Comment: @Pierfrancesco Please do not uppercase "SCALA" in your question title. It is extremely distracting. It is the *second* time in *2 posts total* that I edit your title for that reason.

Answer (score 5):

This is how breakable is implemented

```
def breakable(op: => Unit) {
  try {
    op
  } catch {
    case ex: BreakControl =>
      if (ex ne breakException) throw ex
  }
}
```

Breakable returns `Unit` finally. So thats why compiler is complaining.

Here is one way to fix this. Notice I am using `var`

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._

  object findEl extends App {
    def myfoo(x: Int, l: List[Int]): Boolean = {
      var res: Boolean = false
      breakable {
        for (i <- l) {
          i match {
            case a if a == x => res = true
              break
            case _ => ()
          }
        }
      }
      res
    }

    println(myfoo(1, List(1, 2, 3, 4))) //should print "true"
  }
```

**Functional way (better way) of implementing the same**

```
 def myFoo(num: Int, list: List[Int]): Boolean = list match {
    case Nil => false
    case `num` :: xs => true
    case _  => myFoo(num, list.tail)
  }
```

Below code is same but does not use back ticks

```
def myFoo(num: Int, list: List[Int]): Boolean = list match {
    case Nil => false
    case x :: xs if x == num => true
    case _  => myFoo(num, list.tail)
  }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala>  def myFoo(num: Int, list: List[Int]): Boolean = list match {
     |     case Nil => false
     |     case `num` :: xs => true
     |     case _  => myFoo(num, list.tail)
     |   }
myFoo: (num: Int, list: List[Int])Boolean

scala> myFoo(1, List(2, 1, 2))
res0: Boolean = true
```

**Using breakable is not functional practice**

Halting the execution of the program using an exception is not functional. Functional programming advocates communicating through interpretation of types. Internally breakable halts the control flow by throwing exception.
Above second way is the way to solve the problem functionally.

Comment: Get it! So there isn't a way to implement this code using breakable?

Comment: @Pierfrancesco check

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! :)

Comment: Just curious, why do you use backticks around `num`? My code ran without them.

Comment: @Pierfrancesco [FYI](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), use upvotes/acceptance instead of thank you comments.

Comment: @evan058  back ticks will try to match the value of the variable num with the value of head of list. Without back ticks you need to do a comparison like `x :: xs if num == x`

Comment: @pamu Ahh, that it does, my code was matching anything within the list. So it is kind of a scope clarification then?

Comment: In match expressions, names that start with uppercase are treated as patterns to match against, names that start with lowercase are treated as new variables unless you enclose them in backticks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this trick instead

```
def function myFoo(x:Int, xList:List[Int]) = xList.contains(x)

println(myFoo(1, List(1,2,3,4,5,6)))
```